# UpdateModel prefix - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm having trouble with `TryUpdateModel()`. My form fields are named with a prefix but I am using - as my separator and not the default dot.

```
<input type="text" id="Record-Title" name="Record-Title" />
```

When I try to update the model it does not get updated. If i change the name attribute to `Record.Title` it works perfectly but that is not what I want to do.

```
bool success = TryUpdateModel(record, "Record");
```

Is it possible to use a custom separator?

Answer (score 10):

Another thing to note is that the prefix is to help reflection find the proper field(s) to update. For instance if I have a custom class for my ViewData such as:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}

public class MyCustomViewData
{
    public Customer Customer {get; set;}
    public Address Address {get; set;}
    public string Comment {get; set;}
}
```

and I have a textbox on my page

```
<%= Html.TextBox("FirstName", ViewData.Model.Customer.FirstName) %>
```

or

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Customer.FirstName", ViewData.Model.Customer.FirstName) %>
```

here is what works

```
public ActionResult Save (Formcollection form)
{
    MyCustomViewData model = GetModel(); // get our model data

    TryUpdateModel(model, form); // works for name="Customer.FirstName" only
    TryUpdateModel(model.Customer, form) // works for name="FirstName" only
    TryUpdateModel(model.Customer, "Customer", form); // works for name="Customer.FirstName" only
    TryUpdateModel(model, "Customer", form) // do not work

    ..snip..
}
```

Comment: You can simply the second example to: <%= Html.TextBox("Customer.FirstName") %>

Answer (score 3):

Not unless you implement your own ModelBinder.  If you look at the source code for the DefaultModelBinder on [www.codeplex.com/aspnet](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet), you'll see that when you specify a prefix it constructs the name by concatenating the prefix, a period, and the name of the property.  Unfortunately, the method on DefaultModelBinder that does this is private static and thus cannot be overridden in a derived class.

Answer (score 0):

that was bad decision to use period.  Underscore would have been better.

This means you have to separately define all your ids.

ie. Textbox now has Html.TextBox("test.test", new{@id="test")

Answer (score -2):

There is a reason not to use . as ID/Name in HTML bcs it is not standard. For example, the  will break if there is a dot in target.

Comment: Underscores are used for the HTML/CSS IDs. The dot is only used for form input names.